# Parse Cloud Code to send push notification to group of other users

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I have an app where one user can invite other users to join an event by push notification. Let's say when creating an event, the user add other users to this event, then save the event to Parse. 
So basically I have an array of user_id and I will call a function from cloud code to push notification to those Id, after saving the event.

1)Will the following Cloud code work?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave( "Event", function(request) {

    //Get value from Ticket Object
    var ids = request.object.get("inviteeIds");

    //Set push query
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.containedIn("objectId",ids);

    //Send Push message
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
        alert: "New Event Added",
        sound: "default"
        }
        },{
        success: function(){
            response.success('true');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });

});
```

I am not sure if the containedIn function exist or not:

```
pushQuery.containedIn("objectId",ids);
```

When I search I only find documentation about equalTo function, e.g:

```
query.equalTo('injuryReports', true);
```

2) I also read about Channel, but I still not understand how to apply it in my situation. From the documentation:

> Devices start by subscribing to one or more channels, and
>   notifications can later be sent to these subscribers.

In my case how can I create a Channel and then add ids of friends who I want to invite to this Channel?

If possible, I would like to use Cloud Code rather than pushing from mobile device.

Comment: containedIn does exist, but do you have a list of installation ids for the users, or user ids?

Comment: @Wain: I have user ids

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Will the following Cloud code work?

Why don't you try it and see for yourself, then come back with the errors, if any? Anyway, there's no `response` in `afterSave`. It [will return a success](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave) regardless of what happens in it.

Otherwise it *may* work. Try running it.

> I am not sure if the containedIn function exist or not:

[Parse.Query.containedIn](http://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#containedIn)

> 2) I also read about Channel, but I still not understand how to apply it in my situation

Basically you subscribe to a particular channel in the client. Like this (Android)

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("channelName");
```

Then in the Cloud

```
Parse.Push.send({
    channels: channelList,
    data: {
        // etc
    }
});
```

Obviously you'll need to know the channels you want to target.

You can subscribe multiple users to the same channel (for example you can have a dedicated channel for a particular event) or you can have one channel per user (for example you can name it something like `channel_<userId>` and only subscribe that user to it). Up to you what you need or what you want.

One last thing...

> So basically I have an array of user_id

Keep in mind that objects stored in the database have a limited size. If your object gets too big and has too much data, you won't be able to add any more to it.